# Create-react-app not working - packages looking for funding

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, create-react-app

I installed **node**, then I ran `npm install create-react-app`, then ran `npx create-react-app hello-world`.

The last command did not go through because of some package funding, whatever that means.

How do I fix this?

I am using windows. Here is how my command prompt looks like:

[image: command prompt]

Comment: It's not an error, the process seems to not be finished...

Comment: I have waited for half an hour and nothing has changed.

Comment: ok, how have you install create-react-app ? with npm install ? In official site, it's clearly shown that yarn is used, but you're talking about npm...

Comment: `npm install create-react-app` isn't needed. Use `npx create-react-app app-name`, it will ensure that always latest version of CRA is used. Also, do `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. Read [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: I have installed it with the command "npm install -g create-react-app". This is what the first result tells me to do when I search in Google "how to install create react app on Windows".

Comment: @AjeetShah, yap, that's the reason of the question.

Comment: I don't see any errors, just a "warning" which does not affect performance. If you are saying this never returned you to the prompt, ctrl-C it, then re-run install.

Comment: Can you try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 0):

When you do "npm install create-react-app" you're installing in the current folder a CLI to ease up creating a React template for your projects. Doing "npx create-react-app hello-world" is redundant as you've already downloaded the create-react-app module, if you do not wish to save the CLI software and only create the template then it's a better approach.

Using the "-g" flag will allow you to use the CLI globally to create React projects on your computer ("npm install -g create-react-app" this might require certain permissions) instead of only the specific folder you're on.

Once you're done you must use the command "create-react-app 'your_project_name'" to use create-react-app to create your project. More information here https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app, to start the project just head inside the created folder and do "npm start".

Packages looking for funding is exactly what it says, the developers of these modules are looking for funding.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling x64 version of node and install x34 version solved my same issue.